# batch_loss and total_loss=tf.get_total_loss() in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, backpropagation, loss-function

I get a problem when I read im2txt source code in [im2txt](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/im2txt/im2txt/show_and_tell_model.py).

There are `batch_loss` and `total_loss`: `batch_loss` is computed for every batch data, and is added into `tf.Graphkeys.LOSSES` by `tf.add_loss(batch_loss)` call. The `total_loss` is got by `tf.losses.get_total_loss()`, which average the all loss in  `tf.Graphkeys.LOSSES`.

Question: **why parameters are updated by total_loss?** I was confused by this problem many days.

Comment: I didn't understand anything. How does loss reporting affect backpropagation and parameter updates?

Comment: in my opinion, parameters are updated by batch_loss, which should be computed by each batch data, this is common in machine learning,  in [im2txt](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/im2txt/im2txt/show_and_tell_model.py), all dataset is splited into many batches, and im2txt computed the loss of each batch data and added the loss into  tf.Graphkeys.LOSSES, then comput the total_loss, and finally update the parameteres by the total_loss, so, why the parameters are updated by total_loss but not the batch_loss?

Comment: Backprop and parameter update depend on the loss *derivative* evaluated. Raw loss value is just a helper information.

Comment: oh, my god, you are right, I was muddle-headed, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The summary of discussion in the comments*:

The training loss is computed in the forward pass over the mini-batch. But the actual loss values **aren't needed** to begin the backprop. The backprop is started with the error signal, which equals to the loss function derivative evaluated at the values from the forward pass. So the loss value doesn't affect the parameters update and is reported simply to monitor the training process. For example, if the loss does not decrease, it's a sign to double check the neural network model and hyperparameters. So it's not a big deal to smooth the reported loss through averaging just to make a chart look nicer.

See [this post](https://medium.com/@erikhallstrm/backpropagation-from-the-beginning-77356edf427d) for more details.

Comment: I am using 'tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(...)' to get the instance loss through SGD and 'tf.losses.get_total_loss()' to calculate the average regularisation loss that I later pass to the optimiser. Is 'tf.losses.get_total_loss()' only for error reporting? Because I am actually using it for training ... and seems to work so far ... I suppose that using the the batch loss instead of the SGD loss (that I am using to calculate the instance loss) does not change anything in the process of back-propagating the average regularised loss ...